# How to delete drawn lines on image in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have drawn several lines in python (with opencv package) using mouse clicks (Every mouse click is a point which is connected) on top of an existing image, you can think of this as allowing user to select something on image.

How would I allow to user to delete last point on image by clicking the right mouse click? This is my current code:

```
import numpy
import cv2

points = []

def draw_point(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(image, (x,y), 1, (255,0,0),-1)
        points.append((x,y))
        pts = numpy.array(points, numpy.int32)
        cv2.polylines(image,[pts],False,(255,0,0))
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        # HOW TO DELETE?
        del points[-1]
        pts = numpy.array(points, numpy.int32)
        cv2.polylines(image,[pts],True,(255,0,0))



image = cv2.imread('simple_tattoo.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

cv2.namedWindow('example', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.setMouseCallback('example', draw_point)


while(1):
   cv2.imshow('example',image)

   if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print (points)
```

Is there perhaps an easier way to draw lines(anything) on an image?

Comment: you cant reconstruct the original image once you've drawn lines or anything else on it. You should probably have 2 images: 1. the original image. 2. a copy of the original image where you drawn your lines on.

Comment: Wow, thank you, didn't think of that at all. It helped me to do the job!

Answer (score 4):

Keep a cache of the image after every operation and then simply revert back to the cached state whenever needed. Like undo

```
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global img
    global cache
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cache = copy.deepcopy(img)
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),40,(255,0,0),5)

    if event == cv2.EVENT_MBUTTONDBLCLK:
        img = copy.deepcopy(cache)
        cv2.imshow('image', img)

img_path = "my_img.jpg"        
global img  
global cache      
img = cv2.imread(img_path)  
cache = copy.deepcopy(img)
cv2.namedWindow('image')  

while(1):
    cv2.setMouseCallback('image', draw_circle)
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
    k=cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k==27: #Escape KEY
        break

    cv2.imshow('image', img)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: think you should explain what copy, and deepcopy are... i don't see a reason to import an extra library - img.copy() and cache.copy() work fine. nicely done

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to delete previous lines, reset all or exit. The trick is to use cache to save the original state of the image and redraw all lines again (except for the latest line being deleted), so that you can undo 1 state, 2 states,... or reset all.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('wallpaper.jpg')
clone = image.copy()
refPt = []
count = 0

# left click to draw the next line, right click to delete the previous line
def draw_line(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global refPt, count, image
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:        
        refPt.append((x, y))
        cv2.line(image, refPt[count-1], refPt[count], (0, 255, 0), 1)
        count = count + 1

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        image = clone.copy()    
        refPt.remove(refPt[count-1])
        count = count - 1
        for i in range (1, count):
            cv2.line(image, refPt[i-1], refPt[i], (0,255,0), 1)

cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", draw_line)

while True:
    # display the image and wait for a keypress
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # if the 'reset' key is pressed, reset to original state
    if key == ord("r"):
        image = clone.copy()    
    # if the 'exit' key is pressed, break from the loop
    elif key == ord("e"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to refresh/"delete" lines in a for loop:

```
orig_img= cv2.imread('img.png')

for i in range(90):
    #copy the original
    img = orig_img.copy()

    #draw lines
    cv2.line(img, pt1, pt2, color)
    cv2.line(img, pt2, pt3, color)
    cv2.line(img, pt3, pt4, color)

    cv2.imshow('image', img)
    cv2.waitKey(100) #waits 100 miliseconds before next loop
```

Answer (score -1):

so in case anybody else had trouble with this, it is important to also keep a while loop for the refreshing of the img - won't work without it

```
def click_event(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global img 
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print(x,y)
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 10, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.imshow('image', img)
    if event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDBLCLK:
        img = cv2.imread(img_path)
        print("cleaned")
        cv2.imshow('image', img)

img_path = "my_img.jpg"        
global img        
img = cv2.imread(img_path)        

while(1):
    cv2.setMouseCallback('image', click_event)
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
    k=cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k==27: #Escape KEY
        break

    cv2.imshow('image', img)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: OP didn't wanted the complete image to be erased, just the point.

Comment: @PradeepSingh sorry to hear its not working for you. 
just tested it now and it is working for me.. (did you notice that it is a double click R button? 
also its not erasing the entire image rather all the points on it.. can you describe your problem more specifically so i can try and help?

Comment: This is what it will throw...OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:714: error: (-27:Null pointer) NULL window handler in function 'cvSetMouseCallback'....This is because you didn't specify a cv2.namedWindow('image') before the line cv2.setMouseCallback(...)

Comment: I specified cv2.namedWindow('image') before the line cv2.setMouseCallback('image', click_event)....and it worked without error. But still a logical error as you said. It clears all points which I and the questioner both don't want. Although, I have written my own script to solve all those problems. 
Thanks...

Comment: i guess its good practice to name windows in advance in any case, but again - for me this works without it. this may have to do with OS and CV version..

glad to hear you worked out the removal of all the dots - maybe you want to share your script with us as a better answer to the original question   :)